# How to copy/paste particular column from one df to another by pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have got 'a' dataframe as sample:

```
Date    old
01.04.2020. 637
02.04.2020. 1676
03.04.2020. 1079
04.04.2020. 3091
05.04.2020. 330
06.04.2020. 319
07.04.2020. 73
08.04.2020. 909
09.04.2020. 12
10.04.2020. 46626
```

How to copy/paste single (or several) columns to variable `b` by using pandas library. This syntax `b['new'] = a['old']` does not work and I cannot figure out how to use `'columns'` or other methods.

Thank you!

Valters

Comment: You should create an empty dataframe before `b=pd.DataFrame()` then`b['new'] = a['old']` would work.

Comment: What is in DataFrame `b` and what error do you get when you run `b['new'] = a['old']`?

Comment: I got this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy independently you can do it as following:

```
import copy

b = pd.DataFrame()
b['new'] = copy.deepcopy(a['old'])
```

Above code will copy column data of one dataframe into another.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Ch3steR** this is the answer:

```
b=pd.DataFrame()
b['new'] = a['old']
```